# jquery/ajax: Unable to trigger some codes on pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i created a chat box that has a send button. I want to add a functionality of letting users either send the message in a textarea by pressing enter or by clicking on send message. It works fine when the user clicks on send button but when they press enter it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        
$(document).ready(function() {

            //this but doesn't work
            $('#message').keypress(function(event){
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13'){
           e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                   url:"https://elinks.live/insertMessage",
                    method:"POST",
                    data: {
                    fromUser: $("#fromUser").val(),
                    toUser: $("#toUser").val(),
                    message: $("#message").val()
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#message").val("");
                    }
                });
                 }
                });
            //the rest does
            $('#send').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                   url:"https://elinks.live/insertMessage",
                    method:"POST",
                    data: {
                    fromUser: $("#fromUser").val(),
                    toUser: $("#toUser").val(),
                    message: $("#message").val()
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#message").val("");
                    }
                });
               
            });
            setInterval( function(){ 
            $.ajax({
                url:"https://elinks.live/realTimeChat",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    fromUser: $("#fromUser").val(),
                    toUser: $("#toUser").val()
                },
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    $('#msgBody').html(data);
                }
            });
            }, 700 );
            

        });

</script>
```

Comment: Try with `keyup` instead?

Comment: That will probably only work when `#message` has focus, we cannot tell if it has. Why not `$(document).on('keypress',<.....>);`?